# WebSphere 8.5.5 and JMS annotations crash server application

Tags: jms, websphere

I'm deploying an app that makes use of Spring 4.2.5, Hibernate 4.2.8, and JMS 1.1 on to WebSphere 8.5.5 and Oracle 12.

Resources such as the database connection manager, and JMS connection factory are set in the server and wired into the Spring app using JNDI.

When the app starts I see this in the logs:

```
[3/18/16 15:18:32:717 EST] 0000008b SystemOut     O   [B@631dd237/Set;
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.inspect(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:202)
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.inspect(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector$1.doWith(MethodIntrospector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:495)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 58 more

[3/18/16 15:18:32:718 EST] 0000008b SystemOut     O   [FIAT-CSP-NA] [WebContainer : 0] 2016-03-18 15:18:32,718 [INFO ] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit default
```

As you can see it appears there is some sort of error in the `JMSListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, followed by a message indicating that the JPA entity manager is shutting down.

I presume from this that there is a JMS problem which is shutting down the app.

Has anyone seen this? Do you know what might be the issue?

I'm really stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be class path issues. (Isn't everything on Websphere!)

I needed to remove several jars from the war file that where conflicting with jars web sphere supplied.